# Show PDF File on Vue Component Laravel VueJS Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pdf, laravel-vue

I Have Project With Upload PDF file into public directory and I will show that file like a google drive PDF viewer

Can anybody help me how can I do That ?

My project using Laravel 8 and VueJs 2

thank

Comment: <iframe src="url"></iframe>

Comment: I have tried this but the PDF file does not appear, the file is downloaded

how do you solve the case?

Comment: iframe should work on pdf, please share your code